# Fill PDF form with data and images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn

My goal is to fill the existing PDF interactive form with user data.

Requirements for this are:

- it should be able to insert data into text fields;
- it should be able to insert an image on the XY position.

I found [FillablePDF gem](https://github.com/vkononov/fillable-pdf) for inserting data into interactive PDF forms. But, can't find if I could insert an image.

For inserting an image I found [Prawn gem](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn).

Is there better way or solution for this with only FillablePDF gem?

Answer (score 3):

You can do both tasks with the latest version of [HexaPDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org) which has gained support for AcroForm interactive forms. HexaPDF is a pure Ruby PDF manipulation and creation library, so you wouldn't need to rely on iText and Java like with FillablePDF.

The code for your task would be something like this:

```rb
require 'hexapdf'

doc = HexaPDF::Document.open(input_pdf_file)
doc.acro_form.field_by_name('Name of text field').field_value = 'New value'
doc.pages[0].canvas(type: :overlay).image(image_file, at: [x, y])
doc.write('output.pdf')
```

Note that if this is for a commercial project you will most likely need the [commercial license](https://gettalong.at/hexapdf/) of HexaPDF.

Alternatively, using Prawn with the [prawn-blank](https://github.com/DocSpring/prawn-blank/) gem should also work.

(Nota bene: I'm the author of HexaPDF.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the project is to small for budgeting PDF forms for 625 euros/year

Comment: If you are happy with the current version of HexaPDF, ie. if everything works for you, you could cancel the subscription anytime within the first year and use any version released up to one year from the purchase permanently. I.e. turning this into a one-time purchase. Since the rest of AcroForm support will be released in the next few releases, this will most likely suffice for you.